# Xamarin Forms: Change default page push animation on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In Xamarin Forms 5.0, I created a `TabbedPage` and nested `NavigationPage` instances as its children. I noticed that the page push animation does not slide from right to left unlike iOS. How can I change the default transition animation? Please note that I do not want to use a third-party library for animations. Ideally, I'd like to solve this problem with a custom renderer / effect.

```
private void SetMainPage()
{
    var tabbedPage = new Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage { BarBackgroundColor = Color.White };

    Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific.TabbedPage.SetToolbarPlacement(tabbedPage, ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);

    tabbedPage.Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new AboutPage()) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black, Title = "Tab1", IconImageSource = "icon_about" });
    tabbedPage.Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new AboutPage()) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black, Title = "Tab2", IconImageSource = "icon_feed" });

    MainPage = tabbedPage;
}
```

Comment: Copy [this renderer file](https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/xamarin-forms-page-transitions/blob/master/src/TransitionNavigationPage/TransitionNavigationPage/TransitionNavigationPage.Android/Renderers/TransitionNavigationPageRenderer.cs). See "case TransitionType.SlideFromRight". Adapt as desired.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work 100%. During the exit animation, the page that's being popped seems to be moving faster than the page that's being revealed even though they both have a 300ms animation according to the xml files. This is easy to see if you give each page a different background color. I see a white flash on the right side of the screen towards the end of the animations.

Comment: Looks like the default transition animation is set to 220ms. I changed it to 300ms and it worked perfectly! See https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/cc1d05771a9ba5047aabc935d1d030f709340ae8/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/NavigationPageRenderer.cs#L62

If you can submit everything as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `NavigationPage` as the parent of your `TabbedPage` ? I am using XF 5.0.0.2012 and working with this way

Comment: As far as I know, we're not supposed to nest a TabbedPage inside a NavigationPage. At least, on iOS, this leads to unexpected system behavior. We should instead make each tab child a NavigationPage.

Comment: But it work for me and there no issue with system behavior, it working natively on iOS and Android. Give it a try with new simple project and see what will happen

Comment: Are you using Shell? In the above example, I'm not.

Comment: NO, I am not using Shell

Comment: @user246392 - [TabbedPage doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page) says "IMPORTANT: It's recommended that a TabbedPage should be populated with NavigationPage and ContentPage instances only." Note the option to use `ContentPage`. That is the USUAL case AFAIK; only need `NavigationPage` if you want that tab to itself contain multiple pages that can be swiped between. If you don't need that on any tab, you might be able to use `NavigationPage` > `TabbedPage` > `ContentPage` - though I haven't tested.